# Random barely randomming

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to make a program that switches the location of button1 whenever it gets pressed. For some odd reason, random isn't randomming so well. Button1 just keeps going along the same diagonal line that's slanted at -45 degrees.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int tempX, tempY;

        Random but1X = new Random();
        tempX = but1X.Next(10, 500);

        Random but1Y = new Random();
        tempY=but1Y.Next(60,490);

        button1.Location = new Point(tempX, tempY);
    }
```

I've heard that the reason for this is because I keep making a new instance of random whenever button1 gets pressed but when I've tried putting the random code in a method, I still get the same results. Any idea how I can get this button to actually move randomly, rather than just going up and down the slide?

Comment: You want to use the same Random() seed; don't create a new Random() object before each call on Next().

Comment: First off, Random only makes a pseudo-random sequence. Second, the "seed" of that sequence is based on the current time, and so if you make two Random objects in the same millisecond -- which is no problem on modern hardware -- they will produce the same sequence. Only make *one* Random object (per thread), or, if you need true randomness, use one of the crypto strength randomness APIs that do not use the current time as their seed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without instantiating it for every random value you want:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tempX, tempY;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    tempX = rnd.Next(10, 500);
    tempY = rnd.Next(60,490);

    button1.Location = new Point(tempX, tempY);
}
```

I tested this with two buttons and it works well with random distribution.

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to [so]. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

all Time new Random Number..... here Print in label "New_Random"

```
try
{
    Random randomClass = new Random();
    List<int> collection = new List<int>();

    while (collection.Count <= 100)
    {
        var temp = randomClass.Next(1, 40);
        if (!collection.Contains(temp))
        {
            collection.Add(temp);

            int New_Reandom = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Empty general `catch` is a terrible practice. And the question didn't says anything about getting “unique random” numbers that you're attempting. And your code will loop forever, there simply isn't 100 unique numbers between 1 and 40.