# What's the best way to randomize sin/cos functions in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, math, 3d, trigonometry

I want to generate random points on a unit circle. Is this the best way to do this?

```
static Random rand = new Random();
float angle = 4 * Math.PI * (rand.NextDouble() - 0.5);
float x = Math.Sin(angle);
float y = Math.Cos(angle);
```

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318271/random-barely-randomming

Comment: That will produce angles from -360 to 360 degrees. That's two times around, so shouldn't that be `2 * Math.PI...`?

Comment: I multiplied with 4 because I thought subtracting 0.5 will reduce the random value by half, no?

Comment: @Jeremy, that answer generated random points on a rectangle not a unit circle, no?

Comment: @JoanVenge in a way yes, but no. Subtracting 0.5 means means that the random n's generated are `-0.5 <= n < 0.5` instead of `0 <= n < 1`. But the part that matters here is that the differences `0.5-(-0.5)` and `1-0` are both the same: `1`.

Comment: I too do not understand the 4 and the 0.5.  Why not `2 * PI * rand.NextDouble()` ?

Comment: Also, why lose so much precision? Why not keep everything in doubles?

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks Eric, you are right, this was basis for another code so I just blindly translated into C#.  Otherwise I am using `double`. As for 4 I thought my subtracting 0.5 operation was halving the range, Tim S said that's not the case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create two [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) objects at about the same time, they'll use the same seed, and thus produce the same random values. An easy way to solve this is to make this share a `Random` object. A second, though less consequential, thing is that `4*pi` is 720 degrees, not 360. You only need to do `2 * Math.PI ...`.

```
private static readonly Random rand = new Random();

void DrawRandom()
{
    float angle = 2 * Math.PI * (rand.NextDouble() - 0.5);
    float x = Math.Sin(angle);
    float y = Math.Cos(angle);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I was actually using a shared random. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.